# Catch $.getJSON error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I've been trying to figure this out for hours.  I have a DYNAMIC youtube search, which I use Youtube's JSON api for.  It works usually, but there are times that it won't find anything.  Is there a way to figure out if it finds nothing, and then end the function because otherwise it stops the entire code.  I tried jsonp, but that didn't seem to be correct.  Somewhere I read that error catching is built into the newest jQuery getJSON, but I couldn't find it.

The code is really tedious so I'd rather not post it unless it comes to that.  I'd appreciate any help!  Thanks guys.

error showing that json didn't return anything

jquery-1.4.4.min.js:32 TypeError: Result of expression 'j' [undefined] is not an object.

http://pastebin.com/4rVjAUwa

Comment: Can you show me a code sample

Comment: Do you get a proper response from the request? And if so, what does `console.log` say about `data`? I guess you might be better of debugging this with `.ajax`

Comment: I'm trying with ajax now.  I get a response (from getJSON), but if nothing is there it just ends the function and throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried just using of [jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446282/jquery-getjson-request-returning-empty-on-a-valid-request) or using of [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and then parse output if it is not nothing?

Comment: I did try it, but couldn't get it to run properly.  Do you think you could try and adapt my code for it?

Comment: I changed your code. ("callback=?" has been added to the first line). Could you try it? http://pastebin.com/V2CrVpSc

Comment: Could you maybe provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Did you try pastebin.com/V2CrVpSc ?

Comment: I just did a little change ("callback=?" to "&callback=?"). The new url is http://pastebin.com/vD0WY6qN

Answer (score 1):

If you need to catch error situations, use $.ajax with `error` property:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback,
  error: callback
});
```

Comment: what do I put for the data: string?

Answer (score 0):

sorry but I have not privilege to comment. You cannot extract data from remote server with `json`. have you tried `jsonp`?  it is

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?max-results=5&alt=json&q=phish&callback=?
```

Comment: I tried jsonp but it didn't work.  Maybe it's because I didn't have those asterisks? Could you provide a little bit more detail?

Comment: sorry no asterisks.i got a problem with yahoo json service. and i read http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/ and it was usefull for me

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, all I had to do was:

```
if (data.feed.entry == null)
```

before the .each() to catch the error.